# Connected Component Labelling over Randomly Separated Data?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, labeling

I am currently tasked with implementing a CCL algorithm in a database system (written in C++). This algorithm would assign a label to all the values of a given multidimensional array that are over a threshold, and neighbouring labelled values would have the same label.

Coding a basic CCL algorithm has not been difficult, but in my domain the input array is randomly partitioned across several instances of the database. When my CCL operator is called, each instance performs the operation on the chunk of data it is responsible for and returns its local CCL result. These local results are then merged to produce the final result.

I do not know at runtime which instance is responsible any given part of the array, and the instances cannot communicate with each other until the final merge step.

-=-=-=-

Currently, I have this working by doing the following:

1. Each instance creates an array of boolean values of size equal to
   the number of items in the array and sets all the values to FALSE.
2. Each instance goes through the values it is responsible for and
   checks if those values are over the threshold; if they are, they
   change the corresponding boolean in their local array to TRUE.
3. The instances all send their arrays to the coordinator, which
   combines the results using OR to create a final boolean vector.
4. The coordinator goes through every value in the array, skipping
   values that are already labelled. If the value is not labelled and
   the boolean that corresponds to that value is true, it assigns it a
   new label and recursively assigns all its neighbours (and the
   neighbours' neighbours, etc.) the same label.
5. The vector of labels is returned.

The above algorithm works, but the only thing that is taking advantage of having multiple instances is the threshold calculations. Because this implementation simply gathers everything and scans it on the coordinator, it rather defeats the point of using multiple instances in the first place.

-=-=-=-

Essentially, this algorithm is being made into a divide-and-conquer algorithm automatically, but the divisions are completely and uncontrollably random.

We want to take advantage of this division by performing both sweeps of CCL on each instance, and then combining these local CCL results on the coordinator; that is to say, if two instances produce groups of labels that neighbour each other, we want to combine these two labels *without scanning every value again.* This italicized point is what is giving us the most trouble, and we are rather lost as to how to proceed. If anyone has suggestions either for algorithms or data structures that would be good to look into, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Neighbor connected components (as opposed to graph connected components) requires one to examine the set of all pairs of neighboring (adjacent pixels).

That is,

- Define the set over pairs of points that are adjacent:

  - `{ ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) }` for which

    - For 4-connectivity: `(abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1)) <= 1` and `(x1 != x2 && y1 != y2)`
    - For 8-connectivity: `max(abs(x2 - x1), abs(y2 - y1)) <= 1` and `(x1 != x2 && y1 != y2)`

---

The next step of understanding requires one to know [Equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). Notably, it must satisfy:

- Reflexivity
- Symmetry
- Transitivity

There is an interesting consequence from these three requirements:

- Suppose you are given a **partial** list of equivalence relations, such as (a, b), (b, c), (c, d), (e, f)
- Notice that permuting this list, inserting "equivalent" equivalence relations (such as (a, c) given that (a, b) and (b, c) already exists), etc., do not affect the partitioning.

The point to take is that the algorithm interface of "Disjoint-Set", to be discussed below, is exactly the list of  equivalence relations. Thus, one can process this list of equivalence relations differently, and still get the same result.

---

To *represent* and to *describe* algorithms which compute and process connected components, one should study [Disjoint-Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

One should learn the actual implementation of Disjoint-Set, and also learn how it is actually used (invoked) from a connected components algorithm.

After that, one should raise the abstraction level of understanding - the abstract concept (algorithm interface) of a Disjoint-Set. After learning this abstraction, you will be able to re-implement Disjoint-Set *in unusual ways*.

- During the construction phase, only the `Union` function needs to be called from the main loop.
- The `Find` function is only used inside a `Union` function.
- Thus, one can abstract away the operations of Disjoint-Set by providing a sink for a stream of `Union( (x1, y1), (x2, y2) )` message calls.
- These message calls can be asynchronous, queued, randomly permuted, batched, however you would like to process them, as long as all such calls are eventually processed in its entirety.
- This will result in redundant calls to `Union`, because there will be no checks of whether two nodes are already the same label prior to en-queuing a call. This issue will be dealt with in the next part.

---

Now we will introduce a way of scheduling these `Union` messages for processing.

Suppose the nodes are distributed to different machines.

- We will partition the set of pairs of adjacent pixels `{ ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) }` as follows:

  - For each machine, we would like to find the subset of pairs of adjacent pixels that reside on the same machine.
  - After that, we would like the subset of everything else - pairs of adjacent pixels that reside on two separate machines.

---

To process Union-Find across different machine, one simply 
  * Generates the `Union` messages from the same-machine set of pairs of adjacent pixels
    * Then, filter the `Union` messages to remove redundant ones.
  * Generates the `Union` messages from the different-machines set of pairs of adjacent pixels.
  * Execute the different-machines messages over the results of the same-machine messages.

---

This answer is written in an overly abstract way, because a more concrete answer would require more details about the problem, especially the part about the "completely and uncontrollably random partitioning".